# What property types can I use for my Entity Framework model class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a class like this:

```
    public class BabyChangeFacility
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ChangeFacilityType Type { get; set; }
        public OpeningHours OpeningHours { get; set; }
        public LatLng Coordinates { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
    }
```

Where I would like `ChangeFacilityType` and `OpeningHours` to be some form of enumerated type, i.e. their values should be predefined - for example I want `ChangeFacilityType` to have either of these string values:

`Female Only` 
`Male and Female`

`OpeningHours` would similarly have values such as:

`Shop opening hours`
`Daylight hours` etc

What is the best way to define them? I originally thought about using `enum`s but as I understand it they cannot represent string values so I'm a bit stuck how to do it - can anyone help?

Comment: EF has support for enums. It used to be the case that it didn't, but I think they added it in 5 or 6. You shouldn't have a problem here.

Comment: EF supports enum their value is stored as an int, its better this way to support localization, or in case you add more option to your enum. The string value is the job of the View. If you still insist then one way would be to use Inheritance Strategy such as Table per Hierarchy (TPH): This approach suggests one table for entire class inheritance hierarchy. Table includes discriminator column which distinguish between inheritance classes. So you create sub classes FemaleOnly and MaleAndFemale that inherit from abstract  super ChangeFacilityType with the string value

Comment: Check this msdn article and video explaining how to use enums in Entity Framework 5 and onward.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Comment: This helped a lot Aram, you should have done so in an answer...